# My RegExp pattern alllowing double "@" in email

Tags: javascript, regex

Hello who just have come.

I'm learning JavaScript RegExp rules. And i have wrote email validation pattern. But unfortunatley it allowing double "@" in examples.

Please help me to improve it.

```
^(?:\s|(?:[a-z]))(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+.)+@(?:[a-zA-Z])+.[a-z]+\s+
```

Also screenshot available:
[image]

Comment: can you provide the link of your screenshot?

Comment: Go to the page for the image you provided, then go to the left/top and click save regex and give us the link

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/cC6fV2/1

Comment: There are valid e-mail addresses containing two (or more) @-signs. See http://code.iamcal.com/php/rfc822/tests/ for a list of test cases. I admit it's a very obscure case, though.

Comment: I recommend validating an e-mail address by using ".+@.+" to ensure is has an @ in it, and then trying to send an e-mail to this address. Any regex-based implementation will surely reject somebody's valid address.

Comment: @Jens I often use `.+@.+\..+` to ensure that the url has a period.  Definitely need to try the address to be sure.

Comment: Well info@com is a valid e-mail address in theory. It won't work, of course, but the RFC allows these.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason that your regex allows second `@` is `.` character:

```
^(?:\s|(?:[a-z]))(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+.)+@(?:[a-zA-Z])+.[a-z]+\s+

                                                 ^
```

It allows any character. Just escape it with `\.` to make it dot-only.

Comment: I think this is the better to close my question: https://regex101.com/r/cC6fV2/4 I also want to note that gaps left specifically

Comment: The solution is missing anchor `$`, and there is another `.` unescaped.

Comment: By the way, the solution in this answer is also susceptible to ReDOS (if `.` in `(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+.)+` is not escaped), and escaping it makes the regex incorrect.

Comment: @user3688243: Your regex is susceptible to ReDOS. Use `^\s*[a-z\d]+(?:\.[a-z\d]+)*@` for the part before `@` sign

Answer (score 3):

There is a standard RFC 5322 with a verry complicated regex

```
  (?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*
  |  "(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]
      |  \\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")
@ (?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?
  |  \[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}
       (?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:
          (?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]
          |  \\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)
     \])
```

however this is not a verry practical implementation, the most used standard is RFC 5322 witch matches about 99,99% off all the email adresses being used today.

```
[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@
(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?
```

For a more exact regex you could choose for a regex also filtering on top lvl domains, however you will need to update this regex everytime a new domain gets added since there are near inifinite top lvl domains now this not usable anymore

```
[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@
(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+(?:[A-Z]{2}|com|org|net|edu|gov|mil|
biz|info|mobi|name|aero|asia|jobs|museum)\b
```

Comment: Oh cool. It need a bit time longer to read it. I'll try it =)

Comment: some special caracters like $#%& witch are allowed in email adresses are still being missed with your regex

Comment: Yeah i understand. I'm just training. There are many interesing things whitch i should to improve for the best modern validation. Such as in your domains example pattern. It's super extended.

Answer (score 2):

Your regex seems to be more complicated than needed. You can use this regex:

```
/^\s*[a-z][\w.]+@[\w-]+(?:\.[a-z]+)+\s*$/gmi
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mR5xA6/1)

Comment: This does not allow a whole lot of valid e-mail addresses. See http://code.iamcal.com/php/rfc822/tests/ for a list of (admittedly obscure) test cases.

Comment: I agree and I didn't attempt to make a regex to match all edge cases. And that regex you can see will be hugely complicated. I just went by data OP showed in question.

Answer (score 0):

```
 /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-z]+.[a-z.]{2,5}$/
```

You can try this simple regular expression
Refer: https://referencekiru.wordpress.com/2015/05/28/regular-expressions/

Comment: Yep it working: https://regex101.com/r/cC6fV2/2 but i trying to improving my example. My is a bit different:

Comment: @user3688243 improve means?what you are coming to say?can u accept or upvote my answer :P

Comment: @user3688243 try the second expression too

Comment: "Improve" - make example working right or righter i think. I don't know better english word to describe it =)

Comment: Thank you, thank you all! Your answers was SUPER helpfull. Up to 1000%.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79944/discussion-between-paps-k-and-user3688243).

Comment: This is wrong, since it matches `example.world@gm@l.com`

Comment: @nhahtdh but when i use ` /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-z]^[^!@#$%&*()_+-<>?{}/]+.[a-z.]{2,5}$/` this expression it wont allow normal format like welcome@gmail.com, it shows it is wrong

Comment: @papsk: I'm not the OP. Btw, your regex is wrong, since you have unescaped `.` in your regex, which allows any character to be matched. As for the `/^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-z]^[^!@#$%&*()_+-<>?{}/]+.[a-z.]{2,5}$/` you have an unescaped `^` right after `[a-z]` so it doesn't work.

Comment: @nhahtdh Then how can i solve in the same expression?what is OP?